# mysql error : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

i have installed freshly mysql server on the RHEL server and is started properly.
when i am running command :

> [root@ip-172-31-38-162 ec2-user]# mysql -u root -p
>
> Enter password:
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

i referred many posts but still it is giving same error. i changed even the machine and installed freshly. still the issue.

can you please suggest how to solve this ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/eWz59BE.png surely there is answer here

Comment: i am still unable to solve it. i followed the steps given in that. but no success . please help